# How to pass variable to GraphQL in a non-template based page (part of src/pages)

Tags: graphql, gatsby

While I'm able to pass variable via pageContext to GraphQL on all template based pages ( which use createPage function), I'm not able to pass/modify the context for pages which are part of src/page.

Consider this home page : src/pages/index.js

```
//want to pass dynamic value to $today
const IndexPage = ( {data, pageContext} ) => {
    console.log(pageContext); // prints "isCreatedByStatefulCreatePages: true"

    return (
    <Layout />
)};

export default IndexPage;


export const Query = graphql`
  offers( where : { day: $today})
  {
    ..fields
  }
`;
```

Comment: I'm able to move this page under templates and can use $today variable. So this specific problem is solved. But still good to know the solution for static pages under src/pages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to modify automatically created pages you will need to use the `onCreatePage` node API. You basically recreate (delete/create) pages while modifying the page object. Just follow instructions in the docs [Creating and Modifying Pages](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#modifying-pages-created-by-core-or-plugins)

Comment: onCreatePage is called after page is created. While this works for post processing (like adding/removing slash), it does not help with the data that is needed to create page.

Comment: You really need to revisit the link from my answer :) you delete the page and create it again passing whatever data you want. If scroll a notch you will even see an example of exactly that.